# AutoNumber Column Task ID restart every year

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I am trying to create a column with increment number when adding a new task, but restart every year, for instance in year of 2017, i would like to Task ID looks like this: 2017-001, 2017-002, 2017-003 and so on.

Also it will restart back to 001 when the date is 2018, for instance in year of 2018, Task ID will look like this: 2018-001, 2018-002, 2018-003

How would i do this? Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using a SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow. There's an example here: [Sharepoint Workflow to set a calculated value](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/233708/sharepoint-workflow-to-set-a-calculated-value/233723#233723)

It uses a "type code" and a sequential number for each type code. The same approach works for a year or year/month. I have a blog article I started on how to do this in detail. I guess I need to go back and finish it!

Answer (score 1):

You can create some calculate columns with the formula using CONCATENATE function to connect Year and relevant number.

Then create a custom workflow which is configured to start on item creation in the list and use ‘set workflow variable’ and ‘update list item’ actions to update the newly item’s taskID column.

You can follow the steps in [this](https://dlairman.wordpress.com/2011/01/10/add-a-unique-auto-incrementing-column-to-a-sharepoint-list/) article to achieve your requirement.

Comment: It is very complicated! and i couldn't follow. Is there a simple way of doing this?